# Preventing terraform AWS VPC from creating default resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I just noticed that creating a basic VPC using Terraform also creates some "resources", like a DHCP Options Set, a Route Table, etc.

If you also define those resources in Terraform, new resources are added, but the "defaults" one (without tags) are never removed.

Is this a normal behaviour ? How to remove them or prevent their creation ?

I'm using Terraform 0.9.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default resources associated with a VPC are created by AWS itself and Terraform cannot control their creation. Terraform can either create new resources and reconfigure the VPC to use them (thus leaving the defaults unused) or, in some cases, can "adopt" the default into Terraform management so it can be updated with Terraform.

Route tables are the resource type where this is most completely implemented. [The `aws_route_table_association` resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/route_table_association.html) allows a new, Terraform-managed route table to be connected to a VPC. Alternatively, [the `aws_default_route_table` resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/default_route_table.html) allows Terraform to take ownership of a VPC's default route table.

Terraform also provides [a similar resource for managing a VPC's default network ACL](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/default_network_acl.html).

At the time of writing, there is no such resource for for the default DHCP options, but `terraform import` *is* supported for [`aws_vpc_dhcp_options`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/vpc_dhcp_options.html), which provides a different way to bring the default DHCP options under Terraform's control.

Comment: What I understand is that I should leave thoses resources alone and just create my own... right ?

Comment: Ignoring the default resources is certainly the simplest path. Some people don't like to have unused resources in console because it creates confusion, but if you are comfortable with it then it is the path I would recommend.

Comment: Another approach to work with the default route table would be to get its ID (exported from `aws_vpc.<name>.default_route_table_id`), associate the subnet (https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/route_table_association), and add routes (https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/route)

Comment: @MartinAtkins IMO, associating the new resources with the existing default is cleaner; see https://gist.github.com/farshidtz/b14f68348c9d5c6a62760fa082a390f3#file-vpc-route-option-3-tf